# I am using the couchbase server and I am using joins however I would like to attach a the DATE_RANGE_STR() function to a particular doc type

Tags: couchbase

```
SELECT db1.student_gender as gender, db2.marks as marks obtained, DATE_RANGE_STR('2017-01-18','2019-08-19','year') as date
FROM test db1 
JOIN test db2 ON KEYS SUBSTR(meta(db1).id,0,23)
WHERE db1.type LIKE 'student_registration' AND db2.type LIKE 'marks'
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? Are you trying to update existing documents by adding a date of some sort, or include a date in a retrieved result? Some sample data might be useful.

Comment: all the doc types have a date range. i would like to use a date range from only one doc type in the range